# Sed is not replacing all instances in a file when areas overlap

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I need to replace several words with other words.

For e.g.: "apple" with "FRUIT" in `file`, only in these 4 situations:

- `_apple_`, has a blank space before and after.
- `[apple_`, has a square opening bracket before and a blank space after.
- `_apple]`, has a blank space before and a square closing bracket after.
- `[apple]`, has square brackets before and after.

I do not want the replaces to occur in any other situation.

I have tried using the following code:

```
a="apple"
b="fruit"
sed -i "s/ $a / $b /g" ./file
sed -i "s/\[$a /\[$b /g" ./file
sed -i "s/ $a\]/ $b\]/g" ./file
sed -i "s/\[$a\]/\[$b\]/g" ./file
```

I thought the option "g" at the end would mean it would replace all instances, but I found this is not a thorough solution. For e.g. if `file` contains this:

```
apple spider apple apple spider tree apple tree
```

The third occurrence of "apple" is not being replaced. Also in this, several appearances of the word are not changed:

```
apple  spider apple apple apple apple apple spider tree apple tree
```

I suspect this is because the shared "space".

How can I get this to find and replace all instances of `$a` with `$b`, regardless of any overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty solution is to perform the replacement twice.

```
$ echo apple apple apple apple[apple apple] | sed -e 's/\(\[\| \)apple\( \|\]\)/\1FRUIT\2/g; s/\(\[\| \)apple\( \|\]\)/\1FRUIT\2/g'
apple FRUIT FRUIT apple[FRUIT FRUIT]
```

This is safe because, after the first command, the resulting text won't contain any occurrences of `(\[| )apple( |\])` that were not already in the original text.

The drawback is that two replacements take roughly twice more time to run.

If you break it in two executions of *sed*, you can see the steps clearer:

```
$ echo apple apple apple apple apple apple[apple apple] | sed -e 's/\(\[\| \)apple\( \|\]\)/\1FRUIT\2/g'
apple FRUIT apple FRUIT apple apple[FRUIT apple]

$ echo apple FRUIT apple FRUIT apple apple[FRUIT apple] | sed -e 's/\(\[\| \)apple\( \|\]\)/\1FRUIT\2/g'
apple FRUIT FRUIT FRUIT FRUIT apple[FRUIT FRUIT]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using backreferences.  This should be fully POSIX compatible

```
sed -i 's/^badger\([] ]\)/SNAKE\1/g; \
        s/\([[ ]\)badger$/\1SNAKE/g; \
        s/\([[ ]\)badger\([] ]\)/\1SNAKE\2/g; \
        s/ badger]/ SNAKE]/g' ./infile
```

#### Example

```
$ sed 's/^badger\([] ]\)/SNAKE\1/g;s/\([[ ]\)badger$/\1SNAKE/g;s/\([[ ]\)badger\([] ]\)/\1SNAKE\2/g;s/ badger]/ SNAKE]/g' <<<"badger [badger badger] [badger] badger foobadger badgering mushroom badger"
SNAKE [SNAKE SNAKE] [SNAKE] SNAKE foobadger badgering mushroom SNAKE
```

Comment: I have tried this, but for some reason it is making replacements in situations where it should not. For e.g. "Snapple" gets replaced with "SnFRUIT". I have updated my original question to try to make the wording more clear.

Comment: Your example text doesn't show any brackets, I'm guessing this is not what you intended?

Comment: @Village OK, I've updated my answer. Note how `foobadger` and `badgering` don't get replaced.  The trick was to use two separate `s` commands

Comment: Not there yet. It now replaces `badger_badger[` with `badger_SNAKE[`, because the second command (`'s/\([^[:alpha:]]\)badger\([] []\)/\1SNAKE\2/g'`) matches `_badger[`.

Comment: @igorrs good catch. The answer seems a bit easier but also requires a few more replacements.  I needed to add two more to cover the case where 'badger' was at the beginning or at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "s/\bapple\b/FRUIT/g" file
```

`\b` matches word boundaries. Probably not entirely portable, doesn't work on Mac OS X at least.

And a more interesting test:

```
$ cat file; sed "s/\bapple\b/FRUIT/g" file
apple apple apple spider tree apple tree applejuice pineapple apple.com etc
FRUIT FRUIT FRUIT spider tree FRUIT tree applejuice pineapple FRUIT.com etc
```

Comment: While `\b` makes life easier in many cases, I think the OP doesn't want to match `apple.com` or `^apple`. Also `gsed` can be installed (using brew, macports, or compiling from source) in `Mac OS X` if `\b` is the thing that suits OP needs.

Comment: \b for 'word boundary' comes from Perl regular expressions. In basic and extended regular expressions, you can use \( and \) for start and end of word, respectively.

Comment: I only want to match these 4 situations: " apple ", "[ apple ", " apple ]", or "[ apple ]".

Answer (score 1):

Consider using look ahead and look behinds:

```
s/(?<=[\s\[])apple(?=[\s\]])/FRUIT/g
```

Demo: http://regexr.com?2vl8p

---

Okay, I tested the `regex` in my computer now and noted that look aheads and look behinds doesn't work in standard `sed`, you would use `ssed` with `--regexp-perl` option instead:

```
uname -msrv
Darwin 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

```
ssed --ver
super-sed version 3.62
based on GNU sed version 4.1

Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.
```

```
ssed -R 's/(?<=[\s\[])apple(?=[\s\]])/FRUIT/g'
apple spider apple apple spider tree apple tree
apple spider FRUIT FRUIT spider tree FRUIT tree
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with `sed`. So I'm asking without checking for myself: Why do you combine a lookahead/-behind and a replacement? I think you should either look ahead/behind, or replace by $1 and $2, and not do both.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't test that with `sed` (I can't right now), but I did test it with `php (preg_replace)` and 3 more online tools. I'm not aware of any limitations in mixing look aheads and look behinds with replace. Maybe it's a `sed` limitation. if so, this answer is incorrect :)

Comment: I mean, why replace if you are using a lookahead/-behind? The point of lookahead is that you're *looking*, not matching/replacing. And `sed` is a disaster to get such regexps working with...

Comment: If you try something like `s/([\s\[])apple([\s\]])/$1FRUIT$2/g` this won't match the second `apple` in `something apple apple something`. A workaround would be using look aheads and look behinds.

Comment: Is there some reason why when I replace `ssed -R 's/(?<=[\s\[])apple(?=[\s\]])/FRUIT/g'` with `ssed -R 's/(?<=[\s\[])$a(?=[\s\]])/$b/g'` (to input some variables), in no longer works?

Comment: @Village Single quote your variables or use double quotes around the `sed`. `ssed -R 's/(?<=[\s\[])'$a'(?=[\s\]])/'$b'/g'`. Variables don't get interpolated in `single` quotes.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed "s/\([^ ]\)\([ ]\)\([^ ]\)/\1\2\2\3/g; s/\( \|\[\)$a\( \|\]\)/\1$b\2/g; s/\([^ ]\)\([ ]\{2\}\)\([^ ]\)/\1 \3/g" file
```

There are three substitution commands. Explanation:

```
s/\([^ ]\)\([ ]\)\([^ ]\)/\1\2\2\3/g      # Duplicate each space character surrounded with non-space 
                                          # characters.
s/\( \|\[\)$a\( \|\]\)/\1$b\2/g           # Substitute content of variable '$a' when just before there is a 
                                          # blank or '[' and just after another space or ']'. Any combination
                                          # of those. And replace with content of variable '$b' and same
                                          # groups of the pattern (\1 and \2).
s/\([^ ]\)\([ ]\{2\}\)\([^ ]\)/\1 \3/g    # Remove a space when found two consecutive surrounded with 
                                          # non-space characters.
```

---

**My test:**

Content of *file*:

```
apple spider apple apple spider tree apple tree
apple spider [apple apple spider tree apple] tree
apple spider apple apple spider tree appletree
apple spider apple apple spider tree [apple] tree
apple  spider apple apple apple apple apple spider tree apple tree
```

Set variables:

```
a="apple"
b="fruit"
```

Run `sed` command:

```
sed "s/\([^ ]\)\([ ]\)\([^ ]\)/\1\2\2\3/g; s/\( \|\[\)$a\( \|\]\)/\1$b\2/g; s/\([^ ]\)\([ ]\{2\}\)\([^ ]\)/\1 \3/g" file
```

Result:

```
apple spider fruit fruit spider tree fruit tree
apple spider [fruit fruit spider tree fruit] tree
apple spider fruit fruit spider tree appletree
apple spider fruit fruit spider tree [fruit] tree
apple spider fruit fruit fruit fruit fruit spider tree fruit tree
```

It won't work if your real file has different distribution of spaces or has a strange format. In that case, `sed` is a limited tool, it would be better `perl` or similar with look-aheads and look-behinds.

Comment: As you implied, the result will be wrong for cases like " apple " (space, apple, space) or "pear  pear" (pear, two spaces, pear).